# error PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Invalid `prisma.post.delete()` invocation:

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, vercel, next-auth

This is the full error message

```
error PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.post.delete()` invocation:


An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. Record to delete does not exist.
    at wn.handleRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:123:6730)
    at wn.handleAndLogRequestError (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:123:6119)
    at wn.request (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:123:5839)
    at async l (/var/task/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:128:9763)
    at async DELETE (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/post/[id]/route.js:54:18)
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/501.js:5600:37 {
  code: 'P2025',
  clientVersion: '5.3.1',
  meta: { cause: 'Record to delete does not exist.' }
}
```

i am trying to debug a nextjs project deployed to vercel and i am having trouble with route handlers not working in production but works good in development. this the errors am getting whenever i trigger those events by interacting with it as a user. like deleting or posting something. errors look like they come from prisma.

i have tried prisma docs but nothing seems to change.

This is the error screen

[image]

Comment: The error looks like, you mismatch with your where clause. First, find the post by an id. If the post is found, pass the id field to the where clause.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i finaly found the problem after two days. i didnt

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

to make the page rendering the results extracted from database afresh everytime this page is visited.